# OnClick by PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, onclick, phantomjs

I'm trying to get webpage context by PhantomJS,
in my webpage, i have a table tag that has my main menu and each td tag containt my menu item like this :

```
<tr><td colspan="3" valign="middle" height="30" bgcolor="#a9ae9f">
  <div id="TopMenuID">  <table border="1" width="100%" style="height: 100%;" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody><tr><!-- Row 1 -->
       <td><div onclick="ajaxPageChange(&quot;tm_home.txt&quot;,&quot;TopMenuID&quot;);ajaxPageChange(&quot;index_home.txt&quot;,&quot;ContentID&quot;); ajaxPageChange(&quot;menu_home.txt&quot;,&quot;LeftMenuID&quot;);" style="cursor: pointer; color:#000000;  text-align:center; text-decoration: underline;">Home</div></td><!-- Col 1 -->



setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("");
    console.log("### STEP 3: Click on page internal link (aka FRAGMENT)");
    page.evaluate(function() {
        var ev = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
        ev.initEvent("click", true, true);
        document.querySelector("div[onclick]").dispatchEvent(ev);

    });
}, 10000);
```

I try to call OnClick by Phantomjs and get results, but i do not know how it possible.
is there any idea for this?

thanks.

Comment: can you use jQuery? if so, then just point to the tag and call .click()

Comment: That markup looks malformed. Since you haven't shown your script, so we can only guess. Please include your script and any errors that you see. Please register to the `onConsoleMessage`, `onError`, `onResourceError`, `onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-1_phantomerrors-js)).

Comment: setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("");
    console.log("### STEP 3: Click on page internal link (aka FRAGMENT)");
    page.evaluate(function() {
        var ev = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
        ev.initEvent("click", true, true);
        document.querySelector("div[onclick=]").dispatchEvent(ev);
  
    });
}, 10000);

Comment: I added my script to question